# merge a binary array with difference between each trigger less than certain threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a binary array (plotted in the image below with Time[seconds] is on the x-axis), I am trying to merge the epochs where the distance between each LOW(0) epoch is less than 0.5 seconds. This will allow me to ignore jumps/transients [image] 

 Here is the link to the data that I have. Basically, the red box points should be one continuous low whereas the green box points should be another LOW
https://ufile.io/l7x5q

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? Also please post your data

Comment: Does the numpy array represent samples taken at a specific fixed frequency? Or does it show the times at which the signal changed?

Comment: times at which the signal changed @MarkSetchell

Comment: Are you going to show us the salient parts?

Comment: added some data and illustration @MarkSetchell